# addClass works only within the .click function?

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm trying to add class when the the element is clicked, then I would like to use that class element to do certain action (an alert for instance)

but it looks like it does not work when I use a new class outside the click function, here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){                      
        $(".notactive").click(function() {  
            $(this).addClass("active");      
        });

        $(".active").hover(function(){
            alert("Hello");
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Now, if I put it inside the click function, it works, here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){             
        $(".notactive").click(function() {  
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".active").hover(function(){
                alert("Hello");
            });           
        });
    });
</script>
```

How to use it when it's outside the function?

Comment: You should really set the `.active` event outside the click and then simply toggle the `.active` class on click.

Comment: Use jsfiddle for your code example.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to register event to elements which are supposed to fulfill the selector criteria for binding event after document.ready, as you are adding class after document.ready and binding event on document.ready. On document.ready the event will be binded to elements in DOM who has class active.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(".notactive").click(function() {  
          $(this).addClass("active");      
     });

     $(document).on("mouseover mouseout", ".active", function(){
          alert("rwgweg");
     }); 
});
```

Comment: also on should be scoped to something to a container in the DOM not document if possible. Just less for jQuery to have to watch for changes.

Comment: that above does not work. I'll put it on jsfiddle in a minute

Comment: @Marcel still no proof after three minutes?

Comment: here's the [jsfiddle][1]




please let me know how to fix this, any of the solution above did not work :(


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/erZMx/

Comment: @Marcel your fiddle doesn't include Adil's fix

Comment: @Marcel try `$(document).on("mouseover mouseout", ...` as "hover" is not an event.

Comment: @Marcel of course, you might want to listen to `mouseover` only as well.

Comment: So "hover" is not as good/effetive as "mouseover" or "mouseenter" when trying to roll over the element?

Comment: Thanks @JanDvorak, I could not participate due to internet dis-connectivity.

Comment: I'm going to post another question for "bind" and "unbind". Please feel free to participate.

Comment: @Marcel `hover` is not an event. the `hover` method binds two separate jQuery events, `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602475/jquery-unbind-back-to-bind-not-working