# jQuery "unbind" back to "bind" not working

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

When I click an element I would like to unbind "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events which works fine, but I would like to bind them back on if another element is clicked - this does not work.

any help?

here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#shape1 img").click(function(){
          $("#shape1 img,#shape2 img, #shape3 img, #shape4 img, #shape5 img").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    });

     $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#shape1 img,#shape2 img, #shape3 img, #shape4 img, #shape5 img").bind('mouseenter mouseleave');
     });
 });
</script>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to associate a function in bind eg. bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('entered');
});

Comment: (a) Why are you using `bind`/`unbind` and not `on`/`off`? (b) To attach an event handler you need to specify one!

Answer (score 0):

The [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function expects you to pass a function to be executed when those events are triggered.

```
$("#shape1 img,#shape2 img, #shape3 img, #shape4 img, #shape5 img").bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(event) {
    // do something here when the mouseenter or mouseleave events are triggered
});
```

When you call `.unbind()` the event handler is removed entirely, and jQuery won't remember what it was. You can't simply call `.bind()` to undo that and have it know what code it's supposed to execute in response to those events.

Also, depending on your version of jQuery (1.7+), you should be using the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) functions for adding and removing event handlers.

Comment: Hm, basically all the #shapes when mouseentered do different things (animations, effects, etc). I would like to disable these animation, effects when i click on something, so they stay static, so you cannot mouseenter over them, but when you click another element I want them to be working again.

Comment: @Marcel In that case, you'd be better off using a control boolean inside those functions to decide whether or not to perform the animations, etc. You'd set it to false when you click on one of the images, then set it back to true when you click on the `#close` element.

Comment: Or, I assume you have code to add these event handlers in the first place? You could move that to a function, and simply call that when you need to rebind the event handlers.

Comment: I'm going to try playing with addClass and remove, so they can do things independently..hmm..not sure though

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to assign the callbacks to execute when events occur.

Try :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var myFunctionMouseEnter = function(){
           alert('Hey');
        };
        var myFunctionMouseleave = function(){
           alert('Hey');
        };

        $("#shape1 img").click(function(){
          $("#shape1 img,#shape2 img, #shape3 img, #shape4 img, #shape5 img").off('mouseenter mouseleave');
        });

        $("#close").click(function(){
            $("#shape1 img,#shape2 img, #shape3 img, #shape4 img, #shape5 img").on('mouseenter',myFunctionMouseEnter )
                                                                               .on('mouseleave',myFunctionMouseleave );
        });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: i don't want to add callbacks as each shape does different/independent things when mouseentered.

Comment: You can't just unbind temporary the events. In all cases, you will need to reassign the callbacks to use.

Comment: In another hand, you could assign a global variable to define if the callback must not be executed. In first check in your callbacks would be like this : if(window.unboundEvents) return false;

Answer (score 0):

bind will only bind event handlers for currently existing items.

from documentation [Bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

> Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the
>   jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to
>   .bind() occurs

use On method.

```
$("#shape1 img").click(function(){
          $("#shape1 img,#shape2 img, #shape3 img, #shape4 img, #shape5 img").off('mouseenter');
        });

        $("#close").click(function(){
            $("#shape1 img,#shape2 img, #shape3 img, #shape4 img, #shape5 img").on('mouseenter',myFunction1);
            $("#shape1 img,#shape2 img, #shape3 img, #shape4 img, #shape5 img").on('mouseleave',myFunction2);
        });
```

Comment: That usage of `.on()` is functionally equivalent to their current usage of `.bind()`, it will do exactly the same thing. There's no suggestion in the question that he's working with dynamically added elements, but if he is that's *not* the correct syntax for `.on()` to handle them.